# Discrete Seekbar to change EditText Size

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-seekbar

I am having problem with discrete Seekbar. I have a class where there is a Edit Text. In the same class there is a button clicking on which a fragment is activated. In that fragment there is a discrete seek bar.

```
EditText tryFont = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTryfont);
btnformat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if(!status){
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.actions, fontFormat);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit(); Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here R.id.actions is a relative layout which is replaced by font format class which is a fragment. In the font format class there is a seekbar.

```
SeekBar zoom = (SeekBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.zoom);
zoom.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

How can i change the textsize of that edittext from this fragment class? I have tried passing the value of edittext to fragment using shared preference and storing it back to edittext as

```
 EditText text = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.etTryfont);
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String editTextValue = sharedPref.getString("text", "default");

text.setText(editTextValue);
```

and tried to increase the size of text but it didnot worked. Can anybody please help me please? I am very new to android.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your edittext in fragment like this

`EditText text = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etTryfont)`;

and then if you want to pass values from your activity to the fragment, in **Activity** use

```
String value = tryFont.getText().toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value", value);
fontFormat.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in **fragment**in onCreateView() use;

```
String value = getArguments().getString("value");
```

and then you can set your text to edittext and change the font size

PS start with trying just initializing the edittext correctly in fragment and see if your previous code works

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i am having problem with rootView.. :(

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: not able to resolve root view.
i tried 
    (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etTryfont) and 

    (EditText)rootView().findViewById(R.id.etTryfont)

Comment: ok, then try the other way getting activity's view getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etTryfont); as I understand you have edittext in your activity's layout?  the point is if you have it in activity then the better way to create another text view to be dislpayed in fragment , but pass the value

Comment: And then you'll have no problem in passing data with bundle finding your view in fragment with unique id as you did before with getView() and then just setting the passed value